# Having only one yaxis but at the right side on Highcharts.js

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am working on [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/u2vu7xuk/), and I am seeking to have only one yaxis on right side of the chart.

I tried to set the `lineWidth` to `0` and remove the `title` but still the Unit labels are displaying there.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            marginRight: 80 // like left
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: [{
            lineWidth:0,
            title: {

            }
        }, {
            lineWidth: 1,
            opposite: true,
            title: {
                text: 'Secondary Axis'
            }
        }],

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }, {
            data: [144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2],
            yAxis: 1
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
linkedTo: 0
```

and remove the first yaxis
http://jsfiddle.net/u2vu7xuk/1/

Remove the `linkedTo` statement if you want the units on the right side.